# Make detail side of splitViewController scrollable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scrollview

I am trying to imbed a scrollView in the detail side of a splitViewController. Should the scrollView be added inside the 'View', as displayed in the image below?

[image: StoryBoard]
Or does the 'View' need to be removed, leaving a View Controller and a Scroll View only?

Also, when I add the scrollView to the page, the bottom is being cut off, preventing it from scrolling all the way to the bottom. I also tried resizing the scrollView in the ViewDidLoad method of the View Controller to something extremely large such as:

```
theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(20000, 20000);
```

That did not work either. It seems that we can hold down the mouse and pan, but the scroll bars are always the same length. Thanks your help!

Comment: Normally one would have the scrollview, then (essentially) a view as the content view inside of it!  This is also probably why your line of code attempting to set the contentSize is not working also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ALWAYS implemented scrollviews as the UIScrollView with a UIView inside of it, then your other elements (i.e. buttons, text views, etc...)  SO the hierarchy would be

```
UIScrollView
    UIView
        UILabel
        UIButton
        .
        .
        .
```

Because you dont really have a top UIView WITHIN the scrollview, this is most likely why your

```
theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(20000, 20000);
```

line is not working as intended.

Comment: Do we need to resize the View that is contain within the ScrollView? If so, how do we do this - through the StoryBoard or in code?

Comment: I have found that you can resize your view in the xib file, but somehow you still have to make a call to set the scrollview' contentSize in code.  Most of the things I have implemented, the View inside of the UIScrollView has a static size.  I have still had to (in code) set the contentSize.  I usually set it in viewDidLoad.